# For loop for NDVI of Landsat 8 for specific path/rows with least cloud cover. TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of null

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to filter through Landsat 8 SR images to gab seven path/rows of the least cloudy scenes from the growing season in 2016 then mask out the clouds, and calculate the NDVI. Then export each image to my google drive. However, I am receiving the error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of null.

Can anyone see my mistake?

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Comment: Disregard, I figured it out

Comment: Please post (and accept) your solution as an answer to help others!